# how to replace certain part of python codes using def?

Tags: python, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have many repeated codes with slightly different numbers. I'm trying to shorten my codes

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get (url2)
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
driver.get (url3)
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
driver.get (url4)
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[4])
driver.get (url5)
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[5])
driver.get (url6)
```

I've tried this

```
def opentab(num):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[{num-1}])
    driver.get (url{num})
```

But i'm getting error, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I'm still very new to python. Any help would be much appreciated.

These are my URLs

```
url2 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=2"
url3 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=3"
url4 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=4"
url5 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=5"
```

Comment: what data type is your url is? is it string or array of string(list), you need to define, and add in your question how do you want to retrive the url.

Comment: These are my urls

url2 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=2"
url3 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=3"
url4 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=4"
url5 = "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno=5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your base `url` first and then use python `format()` function and pass the value.

```
url="https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno={}"
def opentab(num,url):
     driver.execute_script("window.open('');")    
     driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[num-1])
     driver.get (url.format(num))

opentab(2,url)
opentab(3,url)
opentab(4,url)
opentab(5,url)
```

you can use the for loop as well.

```
url="https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2022-09-21&venue=HV&raceno={}"
def opentab(num,url):
     driver.execute_script("window.open('');")    
     
     driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[num-1])
     print(url.format(num))
     driver.get (url.format(num))

for i in range(2,6):
  opentab(i,url)
```

Comment: Thank you. The for loop is a very nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can use function like this

```
def opentab(driver, idx, url):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[idx])
    driver.get(url)


opentab(driver, 1, url2)
opentab(driver, 2, url3)
opentab(driver, 3, url4)
opentab(driver, 4, url5)
opentab(driver, 5, url6)
```

Or you can also use driver globally